# How to Un-Bind a data source: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'ALL'

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, data-binding, unbind

DropDownList2 loops to bind data to DropDownList3, but I get error ": DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'ALL'.", if I use DropDownList2 to select a different value.

```
DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

DropDownList3.DataSource = null;
DropDownList3.DataBind();
DropDownList3.Items.Clear();


//generic list

listDropDown3.Clear();
listDropDown3.Add("ALL");


DropDownList3.DataSource = listDropDown3;
DropDownList3.DataBind(); **** <<<=== pukes on DataBind() during second iteration:

" DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'ALL'."

}
```

Help please, this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

In your .aspx page, add new list Item for "ALL".  Then in the property window of DropDownList3, set the AppendDataBoundItems = true.

Remove the following line

```
listDropDown3.Add("ALL");
```

This should solve your problem.